# React JS: axios общий обработчик исключений для всех запросов внутри проекта

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Товарищи разработчики, добрый день! 
Ищу вариант решения следующей задачи: в процессе работы приложения в произвольный момент, на любой axios GET/POST запрос могу получить ответ, дескать сессия просрочена,это можно определить по header + responseCode из ответа. Достать эти данные можно примерно следующим образом:

```
axios.get('/request')
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    }
  });
```

Но по-скольку таких запросов в проекте может быть много, дабы не дублировать один и тот же catch-блок, хочу спросить: как можно добавить одну catch секцию ко всем axios запросам сразу? Расширить axios или сделать некую обертку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно добавить interceptor и обрабатывать ошибки там.

```
// Добавить перехватчик на ответ
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  // Обработать корректный ответ сервера
  return response;
}, function (error) {
  // Обработать ответ сервера с ошибкой
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```